# Wallet passes using relevantDate shows time of notification instead of time of the event

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, wallet

I have an issue with an event-ticket pass on iOS Wallet.

I want to set it up so customers will have their wallet ticket on their lock screen one hour before the show (event).

But when I use "RelevantDate", ticket appears on screen but the text mentionned "Today at XX"
where XX is the hour when the notification appears, instead of the hour of the show.

How can I do to display the notification 1 hour before, with the correct hour of the show?

Thank you :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.